# Can't use opencv in upgraded Python3

Tags: upgrade, python3, opencv

I upgraded my Python 3.6.9 to Python 3.9. Prior to upgrading, I was able to use opencv but somehow I can't use opencv and other libraries (matplotlib.pyplot etc.). What is problem with that ?

I also tried upgrading opencv but it gives me this line
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu is best updated only using `apt` or `apt-get`, the builtin package management system. Going outside that for e.g. a newer python has a tendency to create e.g. version conflicts; icky issues that are hard to solve. Most of the time the actual gain of a (sucessful) update is minuscule.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I will probably install anaconda to resolve whole situation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the installed version of Python3. Doing so breaks your system, as you have discovered to your sorrow.

Repair your system by restoring the original version of Python3.

You can have multiple Python3 versions. One easy method is to use virtual environments (like venvs or containers or VMs) to contain each version. Another is to install non-packaged Python3 versions manually to /usr/local (instead of /usr/share); those won't conflict with your system python3 in /usr/share.

Comment: Actually, I am planning to install anaconda where it has own virtual environments and python 3.9, since I have to use tensorflow requiring more than 3.7 version. Thanks for advice

Comment: If you install anaconda, I'd recommend installing it in your home directory with normal user permissions.